Why i am getting weird squares in my meshes?

I keep getting weird squares in my meshes. Usually only happen this to a piece of my scene and not to my full scene for example, in this case the head.
As you can see in the image the head have weird squares in it when rendered. It dont happen when i am in the default mode.
How can i avoid this bug and cure my meshes from it?.
It happens a lot.
I am using 2.79.

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.
